# NodeJS url.parse( url ).query

Tags: node.js

In the nodejs documentation:

> query: Either the 'params' portion of the query string, or a querystring-parsed object.
>   Example: **`'query=string'`** or **`{'query':'string'}`**

Link: [NodeJS URL](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url)

This part is confusing.

1. When will **`'query=string'`** happens?
2. When will this
   **`{'query':'string'}`** also happens?

I have seen that when I do `url.parse()` it automatically converts the parameters into an object. My code will be buggy if I only support one format.

How will I know if `url.parse()` converts the parameters in this format: **`'query=string'`**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
url.parse(urlStr, [parseQueryString], [slashesDenoteHost])
```

If you pass `true` as the second argument it will also parse the query string using the `querystring` module and you will get an object `{'query':'string'}`, otherwise the query string will not be parsed (default behavior) and you will get `query=string`.